# Use Set() in MobX with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, set, mobx, mobx-react

I have a simple Grocery Shopping app that I want to use `Set()` in but I am getting all kinds of error when I try to use `Set()`. I am using MobX with TypeScript.

## types.ts

```
export type Item = {
  name: string;
  instock: number;
  price: number;
};

export type Buyer = {
  cash: number;
  items: Array<Pick<Item, 'name'> & { quantity: number }>;
};

export type IStore = {
  items: Item[];
  buyer: Buyer;
};
```

## store.ts

```
import { observable, action, set, computed, makeObservable } from 'mobx';

import type { Item, IStore, Buyer } from './types';

export class Store implements IStore {
  items: Item[] = [
    {
      name: "Egg",
      instock: 30,
      price: 4
    },
    {
      name: "Apple",
      instock: 24,
      price: 20
    },
    {
      name: "Banana",
      instock: 60,
      price: 8
    }
  ]

  buyer: Buyer = {
    cash: 50,
    items: [],
  }

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      items: observable,
      buyer: observable,
      buyItem: action.bound,
    });
  }

  buyItem(name: string, price: number, quantity: number) {
    if (this.buyer.cash - price * quantity > 0) {
      this.buyer.items.push({ name, quantity })
      this.buyer.cash = this.buyer.cash - price * quantity
    }
  }
}

export const store = new Store();
```

I want to make the `buyer` a `Set()`. For example, **types.ts** should turn `buyer` into:

```
.
.
.
export type IStore = {
  .
  .
  .
  buyer: new Set<Buyer>();
};
```

And similarly, I should be able to change `store.ts`. [The docs](https://mobx.js.org/api.html#set) don't have a full-blown example. How do I do it?

Stackblitz Reproduction → https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mobx-set-not-working?file=store.ts

Comment: So I have 2 questions, what have you tried already and what kind of errors you have got? Also, why would you want to use Set at all for `buyer`? Set is like an array, and `buyer` in your app is an object with fields, how would you store `cash` inside a Set for example?

Comment: @Danila I tried doing `new Set<Buyer>()` in `types.ts` as I thought I need to change `types` file as well. It gave an error `'(' expected.(1005)`. Yeah, I think I need to make `items` a `Set()` as I want to store item's `name` like `Egg` & increment `quantity` when I buy an item using `buyItem` so that solves half the problem. I just read `Set` docs & it does show objects can be used. But still would be helpful to know how to use `Set` in MobX?

Comment: I still don't understand why you even need Set at all here? If you want buyer items to be a Set, well here it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions67722467?file=store.ts but there is almost no reason to make it a Set, in my opinion

Comment: @Danila you're right. i wanted it to act like a dictionary but then realised i had to keep the `items` unique & `quantity` ever-increasing so i thought of `Set`. eventually, i just went with `map` with a check of `.has()` for keeping only unique items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Map` instead of `Set` but if you want to replace `Map` with `Set`, it works perfectly as well.

I used `Map` with a `.has()` to check if the item `name` stored is unique so it acts like a `Set`.

Stackblitz can be found → https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mobx-grocery-shopping?file=index.tsx

## types.ts

```
export type Item = {
  name: string;
  instock: number;
  price: number;
};

export type BuyerItem = Pick<Item, 'name'> & { quantity: number };

export type Buyer = {
  cash: number;
  items: Map<string, number>;
};

export type IStore = {
  items: Item[];
  buyer: Buyer;
};
```

## store.ts

```
import { observable, action, makeObservable } from 'mobx';

import type { Item, IStore, BuyerItem, Buyer } from './types';

export class Store implements IStore {
  items: Item[] = [
    {
      name: "Egg",
      instock: 30,
      price: 4
    },
    {
      name: "Apple",
      instock: 24,
      price: 20
    },
    {
      name: "Banana",
      instock: 60,
      price: 8
    }
  ]

  buyer: Buyer = {
    cash: 120,
    items: new Map<string, number>(),
  }

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      items: observable,
      buyer: observable,
      buyItem: action.bound,
    });
  }

  buyItem(name: string, price: number, quantity: number) {
    if (this.buyer.cash - price * quantity >= 0) {
      if (this.buyer.items.has(name)) {
        const alreadyBought = this.buyer.items.get(name)
        this.buyer.items.set(name, quantity + alreadyBought)
      }
      else
        this.buyer.items.set(name, quantity)
      this.buyer.cash = this.buyer.cash - price * quantity
    }
  }
}

export const store = new Store();
```

## index.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

import { useStore } from "./context";

const App = observer(() => {
  const { items, buyer, buyItem } = useStore()
  const buyerItems = Array.from(buyer.items)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Grocery Shopping</h1>
      <table style={{ width: 400, lineHeight: 2, border: "1px solid black", textAlign: "center" }}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Price</th> 
            <th>In Stock</th>
            <th>Purchase</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {items.map(item => (
            <tr key={item.name}>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>${item.price}</td>
              <td>{item.instock}</td>
              <td>
                <button onClick={() => {
                  buyItem(item.name, item.price, 1)
                }}>
                  Buy 1
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
          </tbody>
      </table>
      <h2>${buyer.cash} balance left</h2>
      {buyerItems.length > 0 && (
        <>
          <h2>Customer Bought:</h2>
          <ul>
            {buyerItems.map(item => {
              return <li key={item[0]}>{item[1]} {item[0]}</li>
            })}
          </ul>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  )
})

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```